# Does the Psi Warrior's Psionic Strike ability prompt a second Concentration save?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, concentration

The new Psi Warrior Fighter subclass has the feature Psionic Power which has the following option:

> **Psionic Strike.** You can propel your weapons with psionic force. Once on each of your turns, immediately after you hit a target within 30 feet of you with an attack and deal damage to it with a weapon, you can expend one Psionic Energy die, rolling it and dealing force damage to the target equal to the number rolled plus your Intelligence modifier.

Based on my earlier question it seems [the consensus](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/178200/60913) is that Psionic Strike does not double if the triggering attack is a critical hit.

If Psionic Strike is used on a creature concentrating on a spell does the additional damage prompt a second Constitution save to maintain concentration?

Related:
[Does a concentrating caster damaged by Ice Knife require two concentration checks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/139656/60913)
[Does a multiattack count as a single source of damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/130479/60913)
[If an attack causes additional damage after a saving throw, is it counted as a separate source of damage for the purpose of failed death saves?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/152419/60913)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The answer to the linked question informs the answer to this question

The consensus is, as you say (and at this time), that the Psionic Energy damage is not part of the weapon damage and doesn't double on a critical hit. It follows that it must be a separate source of damage, similar to many monster attacks such as the [Giant Poisonous Snake](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Giant%20Poisonous%20Snake#content)'s Bite. Since these are two sources of damage, two Concentration checks are required.

However, there is a minority position that the Psionic Energy damage is part of the attack and doubles on a critical hit. If you adopt that position, then this is a single source of damage and only one Concentration check triggers.

Answer (score -2):

**No, there is just one concentration check per attack**

The PHB section on concentration checks (page 203) says:

> ...If you take damage from multiple sources, such as an arrow and a dragon’s breath, you make a separate saving throw for each source of damage.

In your scenario, the target has taken damage from only one source, the attack you made to hit the target. The needed concentration checks don't increase simply because the attack inflicts more than one damage type or includes an additional damage roll.