# How does Magical Inspiration interact with Magic Missile

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, damage, bard

If you hit a creature with multiple missiles (which occur simultaneously and therefor use only one damage roll by the simultaneous damage rule), would you add the bonus to the damage taken to the chosen creature as part of the damage roll for those missiles and thus multiply by the number of missiles or after the damage roll and only add the Bardic Inspiration die once?

**Magical Inspiration**

> If a creature has a Bardic Inspiration die from you and casts a spell that restores hit points or deals damage, the creature can roll that die and choose a target affected by the spell. Add the number rolled as a bonus to the hit points regained or the damage dealt. The Bardic Inspiration die is then lost.

**The Magic Missile spell ([PHB p. 257](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop/players-basic-rules#magic-missile))**

> You create three glowing darts of magical force. Each dart hits a creature of your choice that you can see within range. A dart deals 1d4 + 1 force damage to its target. The darts all strike simultaneously, and you can direct them to hit one creature or several.

**The "Damage Rolls" section of the rules ([PHB p. 196](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop/players-basic-rules#howtoplay_1191))**

> If a spell or other effect deals damage to more than one target at the same time, roll the damage once for all of them.

Comment: I do not understand the implied connection between the "Simultaneous Damage Rule" (which is for e.g. Fireball; you don't roll damage for each creature) and the Magic Missile spell (which launches multiple separate instances of damage). Can you clarify?

Comment: @Izzy covered here https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109764/how-many-times-do-you-roll-damage-for-magic-missile?rq=1

Answer (score 16):

You add it once to the damage.

As you noted, Magical Inspiration says (emphasis added):

> If a creature has a Bardic Inspiration die from you and casts a spell that restores hit points or deals damage, **the creature can roll that die and choose a target affected by the spell**. **Add the number rolled as a bonus to** the hit points regained or **the damage dealt**. The Bardic Inspiration die is then lost.

You get to add the Bardic Inspiration die once, to one target hit by the spell.

Comment: Agreed. "The damage dealt" is addressing the total damage, rather than "every instance of damage dealt" which would apply to each dart individually.