# How do the damage from the Hexblade’s Curse feature and the Hex and Bestow Curse spells interact/stack with one another?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, damage, warlock

*Hex* requires concentration, while *bestow curse* at a high level and Hexblade’s Curse do not.  This allows all three things to stack.

1. *Hex* deals damage whenever an attack hits
2. *Bestow curse* deals damage whenever an attack or spell inflicts damage
3. Hexblade’s Curse adds damage to all damage rolls

If all three were applied to a target, for every time I hit it, would it unfold as follows:

Hit, *hex* damage, *bestow curse* damage triggered by hit, *bestow curse* damage triggered by *hex*, and all 4 damage rolls get boosted by Hexblade’s Curse?

Comment: Related (at least, the answers there relate to this question as well) - #1: [If I cast Thunderous Smite and Booming Blade, hit, and use Destructive Wrath to maximize damage, how many uses of Channel Divinity are expended?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169268/if-i-cast-thunderous-smite-and-booming-blade-hit-and-use-destructive-wrath-to); #2: [If I roll 2d8 and 1d6 for damage, how many “damage rolls” is that? 1, 2, or 3?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/130244/if-i-roll-2d8-and-1d6-for-damage-how-many-damage-rolls-is-that-1-2-or-3)

Answer (score 39):

None of the listed effects add an additional damage roll, they all augment the one roll you make.

> deal an **extra** 1d8 necrotic damage (*[bestow curse](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bestow-curse)*, PHB 218)
>
> you deal an **extra** 1d6 necrotic damage to the target (*[hex](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hex)*, PHB 251)
>
> You gain a **bonus** to damage rolls (Hexblade's Curse feature, XGtE 55)

(all emphasis mine)

So while they *do* stack, the damage would be:

basic damage + d6 (hex) + d8 (bestow curse) + proficiency bonus (hexblade's curse)

Comment: This answer would be improved by quoting the rules about "extra damage" and how they apply here.

Comment: @Yakk While on the one hand I agree with you, the citation in each published rule book is provided, so anyone with those source documents can refer to them ... the format appears to be a concise citation from each rule source being used.

Comment: @yakk and through the marvels of CC-BY-SA you can do it yourself. This is a collaborative site. I doubt Szega would mind someone improving his content with relevant quotes from source material.

Comment: @Mindwin The purpose of comments is to ask for clarifications and suggest improvements.  I'm simply making a suggestion.  I know I could copy/paste/duplicate the answer and make another with said improvements, but when I see a high quality answer missing a detail I will suggest the improvement instead.  I could also unilaterally edit it in, but that could disagree with the primary author's intent.

Comment: [Found tweets from Crawford supporting the idea that there's only one big damage roll](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2018/04/22/green-flame-blade-hex-divine-smite-how-many-damage-rolls-are-there/): "When something in the game (Sneak Attack, Divine Smite, hex, etc.) causes your attack/spell/etc. to deal extra dice of damage, those dice are added to the damage the effect is already dealing, if any. It's one big damage roll, extra damage included."

Comment: "If an attack has a damage roll but also a second damage roll (not extra damage) that is contingent on a saving throw, the damage of that second source is a different damage roll from the first. [...] Separate damage rolls are delivered by separate attack rolls, saving throws, or other processes. Extra/bonus/additional damage is called extra/bonus/additional damage."

Answer (score 20):

### The Damage Roll is the result of all the Damage Dice

You only apply your proficiency bonus from the Hexblade Curse once when calculating your damage from an attack.

#### Damage Rolls vs Damage Dice

The key here is in differentiating Damage Roll (the total for an attack) vs Damage Dice (individual rolls) when determining how to apply these effects.

The following logic then applies, with the requirement in point 2 that *bestow curse* must be cast at 5th level or higher to avoid this failing due to two concentration mechanics:

1. Hex is active on a target(PHB, 251)

> you deal an extra 1d6 necrotic damage to the target whenever you hit it with an attack

2. Bestow Curse is active on a target(fifth level + to remove concentration) (PHB, 218)

> your attacks and spells deal an extra 1d8 necrotic damage to the target.

3. Apply Hexblade Curse (XGtE, 55)

> You gain a bonus to damage rolls against the cursed target. The bonus equals your proficiency bonus.

4. Your own Weapon (whatever it may be)

That gives you the following sets of damage rolls:

- Weapon Di(c)e
- Hex Damage
- Bestow Curse Damage

The question now is in whether or not these are all separate damage rolls if it is a single damage roll.

#### Let's look at the Concentration mechanic

We can look at how keeping a concentration up works in conjunction with this.

We know that each separate damage roll from each source of damage (PHB, 203)

> You make a separate saving throw for each source of damage

The attack is your source of damage, and all of the bits of that single attack comprise the damage. This would be the same if looking at a standard attack + hunter's mark. You have your total damage which are the damage dice AND the Hunter's Mark die.  Only separately rolled attacks, or attacks that are separate like [Magic Missile](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73190/would-striking-someone-at-0-hit-points-with-an-entire-magic-missile-spell-automa), are considered separate sources of damage.

This is supported by the PHB (196) under **Damgage Rolls**:

> Each weapon, spell, and harmful monster ability specifies the damage it deals. You roll the damage die or dice, add any modifiers, and apply the damage to
> your target. Magic weapons, special abilities, and other factors can grant a bonus to damage.

#### Damage Dice

Damage Dice are a separate mechanic as seen by the use of the Fighting Style Great Weapon Fighter which specifically calls out the Dice rather than the roll:

> When you roll a 1 or 2 on a damage die...

The language around Hexblade Curse is about Damage Rolls, not damage die. The curse therefore doesn't apply to individual dice or to each separate roll within a damage calculation.

#### Damage Summary

That leaves you with you the following damage calculation:

> Weapon Di(c)e + 1d6(hex necrotic)+1d8(BC necrotic) + Proficiency Bonus(Hexblade Curse)

#### There is only ONE Proficiency use per roll

Both the PHB (12) and Xanathar's (5) reference the following rule (emphasis mine):

> Your proficiency bonus can’t be added to a single die roll **or other number** more than once.

This further substantiates that on your Damage Roll for the attack, you can't apply your Proficiency to each damage die.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77865/discussion-between-nautarch-and-v2blast).

Comment: [Found tweets from Crawford supporting the idea that there's only one big damage roll](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2018/04/22/green-flame-blade-hex-divine-smite-how-many-damage-rolls-are-there/): "When something in the game (Sneak Attack, Divine Smite, hex, etc.) causes your attack/spell/etc. to deal extra dice of damage, those dice are added to the damage the effect is already dealing, if any. It's one big damage roll, extra damage included."

Comment: "If an attack has a damage roll but also a second damage roll (not extra damage) that is contingent on a saving throw, the damage of that second source is a different damage roll from the first. [...] Separate damage rolls are delivered by separate attack rolls, saving throws, or other processes. Extra/bonus/additional damage is called extra/bonus/additional damage."

Comment: I still don't understand what here stops Bestow Curse from proccing on Hex's damage. It doesn't specify that it adds when your spells have you make a damage roll, just when your spells deal damage, which Hex is doing. I would think that even with the logic provided in your answer it would be attack+1d8+1d6+1d8+proficiency bonus.

Comment: You should mention that Hex and Bestow Curse are both concentration, so you can't have them both up at the same time anyway.

Comment: @NautArch Oh. That doesn't appear in the current question. Was a previous version or the question or in comments?

Comment: Ah, I see what I did! I just clarified how to make it non con in my answer to make their system work. I’ll add a note to make it clear that this doesn’t work if cast below 5th, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

### All the extra dice involved are part of the same damage roll.

While there is no direct mention of this for features like Hex and Bestow Curse, critical hits use the same language (**emphasis** mine):

> When you score a critical hit, you get to roll **extra dice** for the attack’s damage against the target. **Roll all of the attack’s damage dice** twice **and add them together**. **[THEN]** add any relevant modifiers as normal.

This implies that **all extra dice are added for the damage roll before any modifiers**. This results in the following procedure for your specific case (let's use an unarmed strike for simplicity):

1. Your attack will deal an extra 1d8 from *bestow curse* $$ 1 + 1d8$$
2. The attack hits and Hex damage is added: $$ 1 + 1d8 + 1d6$$
3. When all damage is rolled, add all modifiers (Base Modifier and Hexblade's Curse): $$ 1 + 1d8 + 1d6 + \text{Proficiency Bonus} + \text{Strength Modifier}$$

Comment: [Found tweets from Crawford supporting the idea that there's only one big damage roll](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2018/04/22/green-flame-blade-hex-divine-smite-how-many-damage-rolls-are-there/): "When something in the game (Sneak Attack, Divine Smite, hex, etc.) causes your attack/spell/etc. to deal extra dice of damage, those dice are added to the damage the effect is already dealing, if any. It's one big damage roll, extra damage included."

Comment: "If an attack has a damage roll but also a second damage roll (not extra damage) that is contingent on a saving throw, the damage of that second source is a different damage roll from the first. [...] Separate damage rolls are delivered by separate attack rolls, saving throws, or other processes. Extra/bonus/additional damage is called extra/bonus/additional damage."