# If I cast Thunderous Smite and Booming Blade, hit, and use Destructive Wrath to maximize damage, how many uses of Channel Divinity are expended?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, damage, cleric

How many uses of channel divinity should be expended in the following example?

Example:

- A character is using that a weapon that deals 2d6 thunder damage on a hit.
- They cast *Thunderous Smite*, using a bonus action.
- Then cast *Booming Blade* (at 5th level), making a melee attack as an action.
- On a hit, the weapon does a total of 2d6 + 1d8 + 2d6 thunder damage.

***Thunderous Smite***:

> The first time you hit with a melee weapon attack during this spell's duration, your weapon rings with thunder that is audible within 300 feet of you, and the attack deals an extra 2d6 thunder damage to the target.

***Booming Blade***:

> At 5th level, the melee attack deals an extra 1d8 thunder damage to the target, and the damage the target takes for moving increases to 2d8.

**Destructive Wrath**:

> **When you roll** lightning or thunder damage, **you can use your Channel Divinity** to deal maximum damage, instead of rolling.

I'm interpreting this as three separate rolls for thunder damage, each requiring a use of Channel Divinity to maximize. Instead of one use of Channel Divinity to maximize all of them at once.

One of the main reasons I'm thinking this, is because another use of Channel Divinity needs to be expended to maximize the secondary damage from *Booming Blade*, as it's a completely separate roll.

Comment: Related (at least, the answers there relate to this question as well) - #1: [How do the damage from the Hexblade’s Curse feature and the Hex and Bestow Curse spells interact/stack with one another?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110238/how-do-the-damage-from-the-hexblade-s-curse-feature-and-the-hex-and-bestow-curse); #2: [If I roll 2d8 and 1d6 for damage, how many “damage rolls” is that? 1, 2, or 3?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/130244/if-i-roll-2d8-and-1d6-for-damage-how-many-damage-rolls-is-that-1-2-or-3)

Comment: @ToastHater Note that your interpretation of how it would need to work wouldn't be possible anyway unless the Cleric is level 18 as, RAW, a player only has one Channel Divinity use per short or long rest until levels 6 (2) and 18 (3).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Thunderous Smite: "the attack deals an **extra** 2d6 thunder damage" - this is damage added to the roll.

Booming Blade: "the melee attack deals an **extra** 1d8 thunder damage" - this is also damage added to the roll.

Destructive Wrath: "When you **roll** lightning or thunder damage" - only 1 roll was made, but it has multiple instances of lightning/thunder damage. A single-use of Channel Divinity will maximize the dice.

The secondary damage from Booming Blade is rolled separately and would need another use of Channel Divinity.

Comment: For clarification: with "the secondary damage from booming blade" you mean the "damage the target takes for moving" right? So the 2d6 (weapon) + 2d6 (thunderous smite) + 1d8 (booming blade) would result in one channel divinity for 12+12+8 = 32 damage, right?

Comment: @JoranDox Correct, the secondary damage from booming blade is the damage from moving.