# Hexblade's Curse + Booming Blade's secondary damage

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, damage, warlock, cantrips

While trying to minmax a build for a Bladesinger by way of the new TCoE book I happened upon a curious problem with which I need assistance.
The bonus damage from Hexblade's Curse reads

> [...] You gain a bonus to damage rolls against the cursed target. The bonus equals your proficiency bonus.

So my question can be summed up as 'What constitutes a separate damage roll?' Are damage rolls separated by source? Perhaps by damage type? Are they separated by when the damage is dealt?

For example...

> A creature is struck by a Bladesinger/Hexblade using the special Extra Attack feature in Tasha's Cauldron of Everything; once using a standard rapier, and once using Booming Blade. The creature is under the effects of Hexblade's Curse.

How is the damage calculated? Is the Hexblade's curse damage applied to the initial strike, the second strike, and the damage the creature takes when it moves? Or is the curse damage ignored when the creature moves since the source of that damage has already dealt the curse damage?

Comment: Possible duplicate question: [If I roll 2d8 and 1d6 for damage, how many “damage rolls” is that? 1, 2, or 3?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/130244/63795); Related to your build, though not necessarily your question: [Can the blade created by Shadow Blade be used with the Booming Blade or Green Flame Blade cantrips?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177347/63795), [If your fighter casts Green-Flame Blade or Booming Blade, do you still get extra Attacks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/114006/63795)

Comment: The first link didn't appear in the related posts that i looked through, so thank you much for that :)
I DID in fact miss the worth portion of the material components, so thank you for that as well.
As for the extra attack question you posted, the Extra Attack feature offered by the Blade Singer as of Tasha's Cauldron of Everything allows you to replace one attack with a cantrip. 
>*Pg. 77 Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* - You can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn. Moreover, you can cast one of your cantrips in place of one of those attacks.

Comment: Relevant meta: [Don't signal your edits in text](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3454/33569). Instead, you should edit your answer to read as if it were always the best version of itself; anyone interested in older versions can view the revision history. In particular, if the part of the example that doesn't work isn't fundamental to the rest of the question, you should edit the question to use a valid example instead.

Comment: Related / A situation asking the same question in a very different way: "[If I cast Thunderous Smite and Booming Blade, hit, and use Destructive Wrath to maximize damage, how many uses of Channel Divinity are expended?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/169268)"

Comment: @Medix2 Thanks! That does indeed answer the question